# How to evaluate the following limit + sum: $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{(b-a)i + an}$

Tags: limits

How to evaluate the following limit + sum:  $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{(b-a)i + an}$$
It seems to tend to $\dfrac{\ln{(\dfrac{b}{a})}}{b-a}$ but I have no clue how to proof that.

EDIT: I would really prefer a method that does not use Riemann-sums.

Comment: Try to look for a Riemann sum.

Comment: This is a Riemann sum it converges to $\int_0^1\frac{dt}{a+t(b-a)}$.

Comment: I guess that would work, but I would rather not because I prefer to withhold using Riemann-sums. Methods that dont use it to proof this result would be preferredd.\

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Rewrite the sum as
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{(b-a)i + an}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(b-a)\frac in + a}\,\frac1n,$$
and check it is a *Riemann sum* of a certain function

Comment: I noticed. Is there a way to proof it without resorting to Riemann-sums?

Comment: A way to prove what?

Comment: That the limit evaluates to $\ln{b/a}$

Comment: The limit does not equal $\ln \dfrac{b}{a}$. It equals $\dfrac{\ln \left( \dfrac{b}{a} \right)}{b-a}$

Comment: I have no idea, but I'm pretty sure Riemann sums are the simplest way to get the limit.

Comment: According to WolframAlpha, he seems to be right. Take b=4, a=2, then it tends to ln(2)/2...

Comment: Oops! Yes I had forgotten a factor. Thanks! I'll remove the comment.